# How to send touch events from android test?

Tags: android

It is stated in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html) that

> Android test case classes for activities extend JUnit and also connect
>   you to the application under test with instrumentation. You can send
>   keystroke or **touch events directly to the UI.**

I didn't find the description how to send touch events, please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the various methods on the [`TouchUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html) class. Quoting the JavaDocs:

> Reusable methods for generating touch events. These methods can be used with InstrumentationTestCase or ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 to simulate user interaction with the application through a touch screen.